# Cart & Quote shared between different websites in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Hello Magento 2 Community,
I am posting just to share with community very clearly how to make this posible, as I didn find a complete solution for this problem.

Summary: I have multiple websites, and I want my customer to keep his cart with stuff if he change website.

Comment: Hello Carlos. Welcome to magento.stackexchange.com. Your information is very valuable, but please use the Q&A format of the stackexchange network. Do not post the answer in the question. Please reformat the question to be only the question and post the solution as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Ok @marius done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you have to do 2 main things:

**Firstly:** Rewrite the core function where Magento gets `quote_id`.

Originally, Magento does this in:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Session.php:
```

```
/**
 * Return the quote's key
 *
 * @return string
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
protected function _getQuoteIdKey()
{
    return 'quote_id_' . $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
}
```

As you can see, the quote's key is just the combination of `quote_id` (prefix) with `website_id`, but you need your site to use always the same prefix for the whole site, so you need to do the following:

```
app/code/package/module/etc/frontend/di.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\Session" type="package\module\Model\Session"/>
</config>
```

```
app/code/package/module/Model/Session.php
```

```
[...]
protected function _getQuoteIdKey()
{
   return 'quote_id_1';
}
[...]
```

Doesn't matter the id you use, it's only important that all the quotes use the same.

**Secondly:** Create a plugin to make logged-in customers benefit from this as well.

Why?
is this necessary?

Not really but Magento loads quote by customer, and not only using the session.

```
app/code/package/module/etc/di.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository">
    <plugin name="Share_Quote_Websites" 
type="package\module\Plugin\ShareQuoteWebsites"/>
</type>
</config>
```

```
app/code/package/module/Plugin/ShareQuoteWebsites.php
```

```
public function beforeGetForCustomer(QuoteRepository $quoteRepository, $customerId, $sharedStoreIds = [])
{
    if ($this->_helper_data->getModuleEnabled()) {
        return [$customerId, $this->_helper_data->getStoresIds()];
    }
}
```

As you can see, we are modifying, from a "before" plugin, parameters, in particular $sharedStoreIds, where we are setting all our stores, obtained from a data helper:

```
app/code/package/module/Helper/Data.php
```

```
public function getStoresIds()
{
    $stores   = $this->_storeManager->getStores();
    if (isset($this->_storesIds) && is_array($this->_storesIds)) {
        return $this->_storesIds;
    }
    $this->_storesIds = array_keys($stores);
    return $this->_storesIds;
}
```